# Unable to retrieve location on Google maps -- no error though

Tags: 20.04, firefox, location, geolocation, google-maps

I have been following [this link](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/2839911?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cfirefox) to make maps find my position but it doesn't work. After I "Enable Location Services" on my system and "Access your location" in my browser (Firefox), I click on my location dot, it blinks but it does not retrieve my location, nor it gives any error messages.

[mylocation.org](https://mylocation.org/) on Firefox locates me at a few hundreds km from my actual place. Maps on Chrome works fine.

Comment: Did you try some other web sites, like https://mylocation.org/ ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the elements of the solution you've tried in the post itself rather than relying on a link to the guide you followed. We need to understand what steps you took specifically and the error messages you got in the process as they will help us better diagnose your problem. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: @waltinator The elements of the solution are already there, described as "Enable Location Services" on my system and "Access your location" on Firefox. Re: the error message --> it's in the title!

Comment: @FedKad question edited to account for your suggestion.